# Swift/iOS Controller Does not Retain Delegate when Passed to a Function

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableViewController` subclass called `LogbookFormTVC` that conforms to `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`. In this class I have a function that creates and shows a popover:

```
// --------------------
// LogbookFormTVC.swift
// --------------------
class LogbookFormTVC: UITableViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

  @IBAction func tapShowPopover(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Tap to show the popover
    self.presentViewController(showAircraftPicker(), animated: true, completion: nil)
  } 

  //Build the popover
  func showAircraftPicker() -> UIViewController{
    //Set up modal
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popovers", bundle: nil)
    var aircraftModal = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AircraftModal") as! AircraftPickerVC
    let pc = aircraftModal.popoverPresentationController
    pc?.sourceView = self.view    
    pc?.delegate = self

    return aircraftModal
  }
}
```

I want to move this `showAircraftPicker()` function and make it available **anywhere in my app**, so I move it to another file like this:

```
// --------------------
// SomeWhereElse.swift
// --------------------

//This works
func showAircraftPicker(controller: LogbookFormTVC) -> UIViewController{
  //Set up modal
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popovers", bundle: nil)
  var aircraftModal = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AircraftModal") as! AircraftPickerVC
  let pc = aircraftModal.popoverPresentationController
  pc?.sourceView = self.view    
  pc?.delegate = self

  return aircraftModal
}
```

Note how I have to set the type of `controller` to `LogbookFormTVC` in order for its protocol conformity to come in with it. But I want this function to work with **any class** (that conforms to the right protocol, of course).

So doing this doesn't work:

```
func showAircraftPicker(controller: AnyObject) -> UIViewController{
  //Set up modal
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popovers", bundle: nil)
  var aircraftModal = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AircraftModal") as! AircraftPickerVC
  let pc = aircraftModal.popoverPresentationController
  pc?.sourceView = self.view    
  pc?.delegate = self <-- !!! Type AnyObject does not conform to protocol UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate !!!

  return aircraftModal
}
```

How can I make this function work with any class and pass on that class's protocol conformity?

Comment: What class is your `showAircraftPicker:` method in? If you're going to assign the delegate to `self`, you need to make sure `self` conforms to `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate`.

Comment: It's not in a class. It's an independent helper function.

Comment: If you want to reference `self` you are going to need to write the function in a class extension. You would likely want it to be a `UIViewController` extension. Or are you trying to set the delegate to `controller' that you pass in?

Comment: Yes, I want to set it to `controller` so that any class instance can be passed in and get this popover in return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to create and extension for UIViewController like this:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func showAircraftPicker(delegate: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Popovers", bundle: nil)
        var aircraftModal = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AircraftModal") as! AircraftPickerVC
        let pc = aircraftModal.popoverPresentationController
        pc?.sourceView = self.view
        pc?.delegate = delegate

        return aircraftModal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note how I have to set the type of controller to LogbookFormTVC in order for its protocol conformity to come in with it. But I want this function to work with any class (that conforms to the right protocol, of course).

Great. So pass an object of the type "conforms to the right protocol:"

```
func showAircraftPicker(controller: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate) -> UIViewController{
```

This is exactly what protocols exist to allow you to do.

If you want to conform to multiple restrictions simultaneously, a generic is handy:

```
func showAircraftPicker<T: UIViewController
    where T:UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>(controller: T) -> UIViewController {
```

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting, but then the line `pc?.sourceView = self.view` doesn't work because a `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` isn't a subclass of a `UIViewController` and therefore doesn't have a `view` property.

Comment: Updated with how to conform to multiple things at the same time.